# jquery load() use a variable to restrict displaying certain parts of the page

Tags: jquery

I am building a website, and I want to display certain parts of another link into a modal window based on the input of the user.
I built this

```
$placeholder.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $popUpWindow = $(this).attr('href');
    var $windowNumber = '#' + $(this).attr('rel') ;

    $($popUpWindow).fadeIn(1000);

    $( "#modal-window" ).load( "ajax/project-info.html  $windowNumber");
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');

    $('#mask').fadeIn(600);
});
```

Loading a dynamic variable in the load function does not work unfortunately. When using the appropriate id (#part1 instead of the variable) it works. I could make 4 different sites and load them in separately, but i dont think thats very dry. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

To clarify, i now have 1 site with 4 different div ids

Comment: JavaScript (at least in ES version 5) has no string interpolation - it's not PHP.

Comment: Also `$(this).attr("href")` is super silly. You might want to consider using the DOM API better. It can easily be `this.href` instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `this.href` will return the full URL, not just what's in the `href` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but the difference is irrelevant here, and he probably meant `.href` anyawy.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It is relevant for targeting specific element ID `$($popUpWindow)`

Comment: @A.Wolff OMG he's targeting an ID in one page by an href on another :O? In what possible way is this a good idea?

Comment: I tried it, but it didnt work. I am referencing the modalwindow that is going to get popped up

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's not uncommon when implementing tabs; you click on an anchor with `href='#tabid'`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm miss read it (edited previous comment), thinking about `.load()` URL parameter (`$windowNumber`) but still relevant in OP's code. This is the relevant DOC regarding `.load()` method: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't expand variables inside strings, you have to use concatenation:

```
$windowNumber = '#' + $(this).attr('rel');
$( "#modal-window" ).load( "ajax/project-info.html " + $windowNumber);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/eb1ofd7q/6/)

Comment: @idontknow I don't think you understand your technology stack very well - please consider reading a JavaScript tutorial, if you don't - please consider at least reading the jQuery tutorial at http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: @idontknow They aren't separate arguments, `+` is string concatenation in JS.

Comment: I am very familiar with it, I'm not a novice, either. Please check my history on jquery answers.

Comment: My answer uses the `load` function exactly the same as yours does. All I did was fix the problem with appending `$windowNumber` to the URL.

Comment: If you have a better answer, please post it. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: @idontknow you might want to consider whether or not this is better than Barmar's solution that is both shorter and more concise and does the same thing.

Comment: `As I said, that doesnt work` So what returns you `$(this).attr('rel')` in your code??? Because obviously if this answer doesn't work, then you are doing something wrong we cannot be aware because no relevant HTML markup in question. BTW, hard to see the relation between your solution and your posted code in question. This all question doesn't really make sense then

Comment: Your solution is the same as mine. if `$windowNumber` is `#placeholder1`, then `"ajax/project-info.html " + $windowNumber` is the same as `"ajax/project-info.html #placeholder1"`. The `.load()` function is irrelevant to this, it gets the string after the concatenation.

Comment: When you tried my answer, did you remember to put a space between `.html` and `"`?

Comment: I don't believe you because I know how Javascript works. There's no difference between the literal strings in your function, and the concatenated string in my function. You must have messed something up when you were copying my code. Either you left out the `#` or the space. I have 35 years of programming experience, I help dozens of people every day here, I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Now it works, but your initial answers didnt work.
Thanks mate, happy holidays. edit: i cant +1 it because somehow you need 15 reputation or something.

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle demo using my initial answer.